# Bake/embed XML into exe in Unity3D

Tags: c#, xml, embed, exe, unity-game-engine

I'm using an XML-file to add multiple language support for my Unity 5 game. When I build my game, I have to manually copy-paste the XML-file into the Data-folder that is made when I build the game. Is there a way to avoid this?  Perhaps by embedding the XML-file into the exe-file? The code is written in C#.

Comment: You can add these files as resource in VisualStudio IDE. Alternatively you can add them as Content files and these files will copied to Build output.

Comment: I've been using MonoDevelop to write my code. How can I add them as Content files?

Comment: A quick google search revealed your answer, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383298/how-do-i-use-a-resources-file-in-monodevelop).

Comment: I went and did what that post suggested, adding the XML-file with "Embed as resource", and when I build my game and run it, I get a bunch of `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` errors in the development console